# Self-Referencing Relationship with Properties in Grails?

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, grails, grails-2.0

I have the following self-referencing relationship. A User can have many Friends.

```
class User {

  String name

  hasMany = [friends: User]
}
```

What Hibernate does in my MySql database is to create a table user_user.

Now I want to add a property like Date lastUpdated to the friends relationship. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I may be incorrect here, but it would seem like it's not possible. Reason being that the `user_user` table has no direct domain backing it, as it represents only the relationship between domains not the domain itself.

One option is to manage the relationship in a mapper class, much like how the [Spring Security Core PersonAuthority class](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/domainClasses.html#personAuthorityClass)

```
class Friendship implements Serializable {

   User user //may need some mappedBy config in User class
   User friend
   Date lastUpdated

   ... //helper methods, see PersonAuthority class for example

   static mapping = {
      id composite: ['user', 'friend']
      version false
   }
}
```

And since it's an actual domain class, you can include additional attributes like your `lastUpdated`.

**UPDATE to comments:**
You should really check out the [PersonAuthority class](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/domainClasses.html#personAuthorityClass) for an example - you don't need to explicitly declare any relationships in your User class since they are now managed by Friendship. You can add helper methods in User class to query Friendship for the relationships.

For example:

```
class User ...

  ...
  Set<User> getFriends() {
    Friendship.findAllByUser(this).collect { it.friend } as Set
  }
}
```

Comment: what do I have to do in the user class?

Comment: How would I do the mapping in the User class?